# Open a frame in a jquery dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog

I am trying to load a frame-set in a dialog:

```
$("#dialog").load ("myFrame.html).dialog ({title:"Edit Info"}).dialog('open');
```

the dialog opens but empty, the frame is not loading. No error in firebug either.
If I try to open a simple page then it's loading OK (minus the css though).

Is there an inherit limitation of opening a frameset in a dialog?

I'm using jQuery 1.4.4 and jQueryUI 1.8.6

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an inherit limitation of opening a frameset in a dialog?

Yes, there is, as explained [in the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> jQuery uses the browser's `.innerHTML` property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by `.load()` may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser.

Browsers will discard many of the structural elements of a page and this includes framesets. The only way to display framesets inside another page is using an `iframe`.